# Concatenating array and variable inside an url

Tags: arrays, url, concatenation, httprequest

```
    $pn=$_POST['pn'];
    $ln=$_POST['ln'];
    $logn=$_POST['logn'];
    $wellno=$_POST['wellno'];
    $page = 'SendSmsBulk';
    $usrnm = '*******';
    $passw='*********';
    $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mn']);
    $admi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lrcvr']);
    $msg=[];
    for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++) 
    {
        $msg[] = $wellno[$i].':'.$ln[$i].'/'.$pn[$i].'-'.$logn[$i]; // to frame the message using different variables and it will store in an array msg
    }

$url = "http://www.smszone.in/sendsms.asp?page=".$page."&username=".$usrnm."&password=".$passw."&number=".$mobile."&message="."Hi".$admi.' '.implode($msg)."Is issued you.... Regards";
    $homepage = file_get_contents($url);
    if($homepage)
    {
      echo "Message Send Compleated...";
    }
    else{
      echo "Something Went Wrong...";
    }
```

Getting an error like this **failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**
can i use any other way to run the external link created above....?

Comment: Why you're using array without an index to save a message? I can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to frame a message using different variables and use the same to sent using url

Comment: You might want to use $msg[$i] inside the loop instead of $msg[] having no index.

Comment: for that i need a loop, So is it possible to mix a loop and concatenate in a same line..?

Comment: Yes thats obviously possible. You can use the same loop iterator as indexer. There's no extra loop needed.

Comment: I am just trying....

Comment: I solved the first problem by using implode($msg)